# Configuration error in webconfig mvc .net application

Tags: .net, web-config, web-hosting, plesk-onyx

I am trying to host my mvc5 .net application using plesk oynx.
The problem I am getting is

"This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using  `<location allowOverride="false">` from an inherited configuration file."

I tried to add trust level full
And other solutions available on internet but seems not working.

The full error is:

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> *Configuration Error*
>
> **Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a
> configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
> specific error details below and modify your configuration file
> appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message:** This configuration section cannot be used at
> this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access
> to this section using `<location allowOverride="false">` from an
> inherited configuration file.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> ```
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.`
> ```
>
> **Source File:**
> D:\inetpub\vhosts\granitestoneindustry.com\httpdocs\web.config
> Line: 17
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
> ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

My webconfig file :

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full"/>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: C5EDF6BC-0323-455B-952C-044D40558CB2-->
```

Please help me with a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Namely, you have some problem with the application.  Unfortunately, the configuration in place here is set to *not* share traceback of the errors publicly, so you'll either need to check it on the system itself hosting this if you can, or see if the administrator or your site config can be relaxed to permit access to that section of the site where your code runs.  Beware the security risks of that though.

Comment: @Accoutning4meDeveloper Just as an FYI, there's also not enough informatoin here to work with to identify the error.  The closest we can say is that line 17 of your web.config file is triggering some kind of error - whatever config section you're using at this location is blocked somehow from an inherited config file, likely above your site config, disabling certain features and such you want to use.  There's no way to tell without knowing more about your site config, youro system configs, etc.

Comment: i updated my webconfig